# How to change color of dot and progress on SeekBar?

Tags: android-studio, attributes, android-resources, seekbar

My project's Min SDK is 21. My SeekBar currently looks like this.

[image]

However, I want to change the color of the dot and the amount of progress. I have tried adjusting every attribute that takes a Resource. Either nothing happens or the dot disappears completely. Other posts have recommended adjusting attributes like thumbTint that do not exist.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use **Material Slider** instead of Seekbar. They are actually the same in function and appearence.

[Here is the documentation to Sliders](https://material.io/components/sliders)

[Also theming sliders is very easy](https://material.io/components/sliders/android#theming-sliders)

Comment: Material Slider is not one of the available widgets.

Comment: please refer to the documentation i linked for implementation of material slider, full name of silder is **com.google.android.material.slider.Slider**

Comment: and also import material dependency if not already added